# c++ opencv 2.4.9 imread then imwrite，color changed

Tags: c++, image, opencv

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>  
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  
 #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;   
 int main()
{    
    Mat srcImage = imread(img_path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    imwrite("./test.png", srcImage);
    return 0;
}
```

i read a image,then save to file.but the image color is changed.this is why??
[compare of src&dst image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YTMu.jpg)

Comment: opencv doesn't handle color formats like adobeRGB vs. sRGB. Another thing is that if you dont specify the right flag, all images are read as 3 channel with 8 bit each, even if the image is mono 16 bit. This will introduce differences when saving back.

Comment: @Micka 
 `
    import os
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    # load
    img = Image.open('8.jpg')
    img1 = Image.fromarray(np.array(img),mode='CMYK')
    img1.save('new_cat.jpg')
`
use this python code , i can save the real color。can opencv c++  Do something similar?and do u know how to confirm color formats

Comment: I don't think OpenCV supports reading 4 channels JPEG image. Is `'8.jpg'` really in CMYK color format?

Comment: I'm not really sure.but it seem to work.how to make sure its color format@Rotem.thanks